# How can I sync sent mail from another device on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, mail.app

On iOS 6.0.2. Can't see nor search my Sent emails other than the ones I actually sent from the iPad. I'm using Yahoo Business Mail on IMAP settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other device that is sending email probably isn't saving them to the Sent folder.

If you're using the Yahoo! website to send mail, you can go to Mail Options > General > Sending Messages to fix this. See the their support article for screenshots and more info: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/options/options-17.html

If the other device is using OS X Mail, go to Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Mailbox Behaviors and make sure "Store Sent messages on server" is checked.

For Mail on iOS, Settings > General > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > (your account) > Account > Advanced and make sure your sent mailbox is on the server.